# Fonts are not rendered on a webpage

Tags: fonts, webfonts, eot, svg-font

I've created a web-version of the *Lato* font using *Font Squirrel*.

I've also setup a [test-suite in *Plunker*](http://goo.gl/oxHXAm) in order to test and debug it.

#### Some fonts are not rendered:

- SVG is not rendered in Safari 5.1 (both on Windows and on OS X)
- EOT is not rendered in Internet Explorer 11

When rendering EOT in IE 11 I'm getting an *"unknown error"* in debugging console.

#### Compatibility tables:

- [EOT](http://caniuse.com/#search=EOT)
- [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts)

What can be the reason for this? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the EOT it's probably coming from the file itself. Try [ttf2eot](https://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/) instead of FontSquirrel.

For the error itself check [this comment](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader/issues/173#issuecomment-33614570) and, if it's happening for previous versions of IE, this [blog post](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/) as well.

Safari 5.1 supports WOFF so the problem is moot since it should be picked up before in your @font-face rule.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try to do as you suggested. I'm just trying to verify that SVG file is working correctly. Is there another way? According to compat tables Safari should render SVG correctly.

Comment: @SlavaFominII SVG support is necessary for somewhat old smartphones. I am not fond of it cause it lacks certain features which I consider important like kerning for example.